# Add XML Parameters in API request

Tags: xml, api, soap, google-apps-script

Using SoapUI, I had errors until I corrected the parameters (I now get the desired response). Using Apps Script, I am struggling with the identical error, but I can't seem to get the XML parameters added properly, the example below is the last method I tried.

Per the API documentation:

```
"Wrap the following XML structure in a variable called 'callmeasurement_xml_input' "
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<callmeasurement username="abc" password="123" api="1"/>
```

The functioning "Parameters" in SoapUI are:

```
?callmeasurement_xml_input=<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?><callmeasurement username="abc" password="123" api="1111"/>
```

Here is my current (non working) AppsScript:

```
function apiRequest(){

  var url = 'http://api.callmeasurement.com/api/dnis_list.cfm';

  var rawXML = '<callmeasurement_xml_input>'
  + '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>'
  + '<callmeasurement username="abc" password="123" api="1111"/>'
  + '</callmeasurement_xml_input>';

  var options = {
    'contentType': 'application/xml',
    'method': 'POST',
    'payload': rawXML
  };
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  Logger.log(response.getContentText());
  // Returns an error
}
```

Comment: The text you've assigned to rawXML looks invalid.

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: The error is a generic response from the hos. It's the exact same response I received in SoapUI until I correctly added the parameters.

            `<h2>An unexpected error occurred.</h2>
            <p>Please provide the following information to technical support:</p>
            <p>Error Event: </p>
            <p>Error details:<br>`

Comment: In SoapUI, there's a button to add parameters with a name. I set the name to "callmeasurement_xml_input" and the parameter to: "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?><callmeasurement username="abc" password="123" api="1111"/>" which resolved the issue and provided the correct response (SoapUI only). 

I feel like the "Wrap the following XML structure in a variable called 'callmeasurement_xml_input" part is the issue. I'm not sure how to do that in Apps Script.

Comment: `var rawXML ={ 'callmeasurement_xml_input':
  '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>'
  + '<callmeasurement username="abc" password="123" api="1111"/>'
  };
`

Comment: Still no luck. Here is the raw request that is functioning in SoapUI:
`POST https://api.callmeasurement.com/api/dnis_list.cfm?callmeasurement_xml_input=%3C%3Fxml%20version%3D%221.0%22%20encoding%3D%22utf-16%22%3F%3E%20%20%3Ccallmeasurement%20username%3D%22abc%22%20password%3D%22123%22%20api%3D%22111=&CFTOKEN= HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Content-Type: application/xml
Host: api.callmeasurement.com
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Content-Type: application/xml
Content-Length: 0
Host: api.callmeasurement.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)
`

Comment: Just encode it in url. Seems that's what is happening.

Comment: That works, BUT the CFID and CFTOKEN values in the url string are only found in the manual(SoapUI) response. Hopefully there's a solution that doesn't require a third-party application every time I write a new script.

Comment: How is CFID and CFTOKEN created? Reply with `@I'-'I` to notify me.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of wrapping the XML in a callmeasurement_xml_input element, and posting it in the payload, the XML should be encoded and passed in a callmeasurement_xml_input query parameter.

```
function apiRequest(){

  var rawXML = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>'
  + '<callmeasurement username="abc" password="123" api="1111"/>';

  var url = 'http://api.callmeasurement.com/api/dnis_list.cfm'
  + '?callmeasurement_xml_input=' + encodeURIComponent(rawXML);

  var options = {'method': 'POST'};
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  Logger.log(response.getContentText());
}
```